# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported(Ajax, Spring)

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I trying send PUT request. I have *serialazible class* and controller with necessary settings, my request has *contentType: "application/json*".

**FlightDto:**

```
 public class FlightDto implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String navigation;

    public FlightDto() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNavigation() {
        return navigation;
    }

    public void setNavigation(String navigation) {
        this.navigation = navigation;
    }

}
```

**PUT request:**

```
  function editNavigation() {
    var flight={
        id:idAction.replace('edit',''),
        navigation:newNavigation
    };
    console.log(flight);
    var prefix = '/airline/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: prefix +'flights/' + idAction.replace('edit',''),
        data: JSON.stringify(flight),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(receive) {
            $("#adminTable").empty();
            $("#informationP").replaceWith(receive);
            $("#hiddenLi").removeAttr('style');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error edited flight');
        }
    });
}
```

console.log(flight); - *Object {id: "7", navigation: "sdfdsfsd"}*

**FlightController:**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = prefix + "/flights/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateFlight(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody FlightDto flightDto) {
        String returnText = "Flight edited successful";
        String str1 = flightDto.getNavigation();
        String str2 = id;
        return returnText;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
```

How fix this error?

Comment: You should add `dataType: "json"` in ajax. Or add headers like `headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the content type in your header not in the payload using headers attribute

```
   data: JSON.stringify(flight),
   headers:{contentType: "application/json"}
```

Comment: changed: *headers:{contentType: "application/json"}*. Why I have only   alert('Error edited flight'); now?